# double value Dropping scale value after saving to MS SQL using Dapper DynamicParameters

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I am missing a scale (see example image below).
Even though I specified the precision and scale in my dynamic parameter, I am still loosing the last non zero value.

Not sure what I missed out to do.

```
const string insertSql = @"insert into DATATABLE (FEES_VALUE) VALUES (@DataValue)";
var doubleValue = 0.06930846118065210000;
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("DataValue", doubleValue, dbType: DbType.Decimal, precision: 28, scale: 20);

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    var data = conn.Execute(query, parameters, commandType: CommandType.Text, commandTimeout: 600);
}
```

[image: Example]

**UPDATE:** 
Apparently, it was not a Dapper issue.
It was the data type that I used.
Below are the results after I tested in more detail (Thanks Cameron for suggesting)

as decimal  0.00058235001858449700
  as double   0.00058235001858450000

Comment: This is interesting because `0.06930846118065210000` can be represented exactly as a double. However, if you choose to pass it as a decimal instead (`0.06930846118065210000m`), does this affect the result?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that out Cameron. I tested your point and found out that it is not a Dapper issue. It was the data type                                                                                
  as decimal  0.00058235001858449700 
  as double   0.00058235001858450000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the data type to decimal instead of double solved my problem